# Is it correct to place the adverb 'now' in this position in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> Zoom calls were a thing, no longer a mere irritation of the lectures and offices we had escaped, but necessary now to connect with family less than twenty miles away.

Am I correct to put 'now' after 'necessary'? Technically it is grammatically incorrect to put an adverb after an adjective, but in my opinion sounds better here. Is it because 'now' is actually modifying the infinitive 'to connect'?

Comment: No. You need to keep parallel: _Zoom calls were a thing — **no longer** [...], **but now** [...]_

Comment: I don't believe that "Technically it is grammatically incorrect to put an adverb after an adjective" business anyway, but so far as I'm concerned it's just a ***stylistic choice*** whether to put "adverbial" ***now*** before or after the adjective ***necessary*** (or even *at the end of the sentence*, but that would be a stylistically poor choice in this *exact* context).

Comment: I'm missing something. "Zoom calls were a thing, (no longer) a mere irritation." Do you mean they were annoying but are needed now? No longer annoying? No longer just annoying but a necessary evil?

Comment: TinfoilHat: Personally I think that that makes the sentence sound a bit clinical when it's supposed to sound like a conversation.
FumbleFingers: Thanks, that makes me feel more confident to just leave it how it is.
Yosef Baskin: Were annoying but are needed now. I guess that's unclear when out of context.